# How can I write one pattern rule for any library archives created in build directory?

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I want to define a pattern rule for building any library archive. The below example works (assume the object files already exist in the build directory):

```
all: librot.a( build/rot13.o build/rot47.o )

ARFLAGS := -rcsU

(%): %
    $(AR) $(ARFLAGS) $@ $%
```

However, I prefer to create the library archive in the build directory as well, but this no longer works. The pattern rule no longer matches.

```
all: build/librot.a( build/rot13.o build/rot47.o )

ARFLAGS := -rcsU

(%): %
    $(AR) $(ARFLAGS) $@ $%
```

I know I can modify the rule to this:

```
build/librot.a(%): %
    $(AR) $(ARFLAGS) $@ $%
```

but I don't want to have to define a new pattern rule for every library. How can I write one pattern rule for any library archives created in the build directory?

Comment: If the assumption "the object files already exist in the build directory" holds
your GNU Make 4.2 Makefile needs 2 lines: (1) `all: build/librot.a( build/rot13.o build/rot47.o )` and (2) `ARFLAGS := -rcsU`. The built-in `(%): %` rule does the rest.

Comment: @urcodebetterznow: thanks for the comment. I think you are right and I screwed up when I posted this question. I tried to simplify the situation when writing my question and actually "fixed" the problem in doing so. The issue was another pattern rule I had defined was getting matched with higher precedence than the (%): % rule.